# How to read json file into Clojure defrecord (to be searched later)

Tags: json, clojure

I have created a defrecord in a Clojure REPL:

```
user=> (defrecord Data [column1 column2 column3])
user.Data
```

How do I automate adding data to this record by reading in a .json file? Each of the columns in the defrecord corresponds exactly to a key in the json data. If the file contained a single record it would look similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "column1" : "value1"
    "column2" : "value2"
    "column3" : "value3"
  }
]
```

But there are many thousands of such records in the file.

I can slurp the contents of the file like this:

```
(json/read-json (slurp "path/to/file.json")))
```

The dependencies for the read-json function are added to the project.clj file found in the directory where I am running `lein repl` from the command line: `:dependencies [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.1"]`.

I would just like to be able to search the values of the records using a Clojure function, such that the value I am passing to the search function is between the values of a single record's column1 and column2 values (i.e., *nth-record.column1.value* **<=** *query* **<=** *nth-record.column2.value*). Once I've found a matching record, I want to return the value of another column in that same record (nth-record.column3.value). The values of columns 1 and 2 will be unique, representing a non-overlapping range of values. The value of column3 is not unique.

This seems like a fairly trivial task, but I can't figure out how to do it using the Clojure documentation or the examples I've found online. It doesn't matter to me how the records are stored internally in Clojure, as long as I can search them and return the value of a related field in the same record.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `data.json` package:

```
(require '[clojure.data.json :as json])
```

Read values into memory:

```
(def all-records (json/read-str (slurp "path/to/file.json")
                :key-fn keyword))
;; ==> [ { :column1 "value1", :column2 "value2", :column3 "value3" }, ...]
```

Find matching records:

```
(def query "some-value")
(def matching (filter #(and (< (:column1 %) query) (< query (:column2 %))) all-records))
```

Get column3:

```
(map :column3 matching)
```

Collecting it all together (and making it more flexible):

```
(defn find-matching [select-fn result-fn records]
   (map result-fn (filter select-fn records)))

(defn select-within [rec query]
  (and (< (:column1 rec) query) (< query (:column2 rec))))

(find-matching #(select-within % "some-value") :column3 all-records)
```

Comment: ffriend, thanks very much for your help. I'm still having some trouble with the find-matching function. The repl is complaining that I'm not passing enough arguments to the function. Should all-records be passed as a third argument after :column3 ?

Comment: @ChrisDevo: yeah, sorry, didn't have REPL at hand. I have updated my code.

Comment: The values in my map are stored as strings. To do numerical comparisons I had to modify the 
`(:column1 rec)` to `(bigint (:column1 rec))`, 
otherwise I would get a 
`ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.lt (Numbers.java:219)`
thrown.

Answer (score 1):

1. Should probably use cheshire for speed.
2. If your queries get sufficiently complex, consider lucene, clojure has a nice wrapper.

I think you're thinking records are somehow more suitable for this than maps, as far as I can tell, you're not using any features that make records special like polymorphism.  There might be a way to make cheshire spit out records, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks, gtrak. I wasn't sure I need defrecords either. I'm still getting used to the functional paradigm where code is data and vice versa.